# Add a new module to an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the application:

`var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);`

I installed a module but not yet fully included into my app.

How to add `angular.module('myModule', ['decipher.tags', 'ui.bootstrap.typeahead'];`, so that I can use it into my application?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute','myModule']);
```